# How can I show the table I'm creating in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

How can I see my output table in SQL?

Comment: I highly recommend you find a beginner SQL tutorial and go through it

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question should be answered by consulting product documentation or an available online tutorial. Stack Overflow is not the appropriate forum for the question.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the table can be viewed by this simple SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM mmm.test
```

For basic information about sql like this I can recommend the following [sql introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp).

Comment: Or expand **Tables** in the navigation tree on the left of you screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can query it using

`SELECT * FROM mmm.test`

You can also click on the `Tables` on left side and select your table to view contents